# Android app, putBytes to Firebase not working

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

Im (doing tutorial on YT) trying to put my image to firebase,
As far as I can see, I can't connect to the database, but I don't know where the problem is and what I am doing wrong

but when I try I have something like this in logcat:

```
2021-11-01 06:57:40.660 32702-32702/pl.edu.pb.mymemory E/CreateActivity: Exception with Firebase storage
    com.google.firebase.storage.StorageException: The operation retry limit has been exceeded.
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.snapStateImpl(UploadTask.java:524)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.snapStateImpl(UploadTask.java:50)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.snapState(StorageTask.java:343)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.getFinalResult(StorageTask.java:453)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.getResult(StorageTask.java:273)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.getResult(StorageTask.java:41)
```

There is my function:

```
private fun saveDataToFirebase() {
        val customGameName = etGameName.text.toString()
        Log.i(TAG, "Save data to Firebase")
        var didEncounteredError = false
        val uploadedImageUrls = mutableListOf<String>()

        for ((index,photoUri) in chosenImageUris.withIndex()) {
            //downgrading the quality of the image
            val imageByteArray =  getImageByteArray(photoUri)
            val filePath = "images/$customGameName/${System.currentTimeMillis()}-${index}.jpg"
            val photoReference = storage.reference.child(filePath)
            Log.i(TAG, "Trying to upload: ${photoReference}")
            //wait until it succeeds or fails
            photoReference.putBytes(imageByteArray)
                .continueWithTask { photoUploadTask ->
                    Log.i(TAG, "Uploaded bytes: ${photoUploadTask.result?.bytesTransferred}")
                    photoReference.downloadUrl
                }.addOnCompleteListener { downloadUrlTask ->
                    if (!downloadUrlTask.isSuccessful) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Exception with Firebase storage", downloadUrlTask.exception)
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to upload image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        didEncounteredError = true
                        return@addOnCompleteListener
                    }
                    if(didEncounteredError){
                        return@addOnCompleteListener
                    }
                    val downloadUrl = downloadUrlTask.result.toString()
                    uploadedImageUrls.add(downloadUrl)
                    Log.i(TAG, "Finished uploading $photoUri, num uploaded ${uploadedImageUrls.size}")
                    if(uploadedImageUrls.size == chosenImageUris.size) {
                        handleAllImagesUploaded(customGameName, uploadedImageUrls)
                    }
                }
        }
    }
```

[My repository on git](https://github.com/waleery/MyMemory)

Comment: As the error says, there are some limitations when it comes to how many retries you can perform. Try to do them less often.

Comment: When I waited and tried again, it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was wrong date on phone.

Fixing date resolved an issue